# Pinax : Out of the blue : "no such table: profiles_profile"

Tags: django, pinax

Note : pinax 0.7.3

I'm just running a clone of basic_project with sqlite3.

It was working fine yest. Hibernated my laptop and when I opened and 
try to login again, I got -
`no such table: profiles_profile`

Opened the database dev.db using the sqlite3 client and I don't see it 
there.

Stopped the server, deleted the DB, did a syncdb which created a 
completely new dev.db and it too is missing the table. 
I was looking into the views.py of the profiles app, but I'm sure I 
didn't do any Dodo in it.

The settings.py has the `basic_profiles` as installed apps.

The exception shows the query fired as -
`'SELECT "profiles_profile"."id", "profiles_profile"."user_id", "profiles_profile"."name", "profiles_profile"."about", "profiles_profile"."location", "profiles_profile"."website" FROM "profiles_profile" WHERE "profiles_profile"."user_id" = ? '`

That table structure is the same as of `basic_profiles`, Can't figure where I could've mistyped while viewing these files.

Any pointers ?

Comment: I have the exact same problem..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Didn't figure where I messed up, hence I cloned the project again and haven't seen the issue.

Pretty sure it was my fault though.